# Java - Print Dialog for full screen window

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have a full screen application, and I need to print.  For other popup screens I've used JInternalFrames, but now I need to use PrintJob.  My current code is as follows:

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintable(receipt);
if (printJob.printDialog())
    try { 
        printJob.print();
    } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
    }
```

But that of course doesn't show above the full screen window, so in order to see the dialog you have to leave my application(with alt-tab, or windows key or something like that).  Obviously that isn't particularly practical. So how can I print from my fullscreen application without the user having to minimize the program?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a PrinterJob?  Since you have a Printable object, you could embed the AWT component returned by `PrintService.getServiceUIFactory().getUI(PANEL_UI)` (or JCOMPONENT_UI if Swing is acceptable) in your full-screen window, and then print using `new SimpleDoc(receipt, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null)`.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't checked up on this in a while, but:
Just so we are clear, would this allow a UI or something that lets the user choose things like printers, or is this just so that I can print something?  Because I really would like to allow the user to change print settings ect. I think that making the program the size of the screen, and undecorated could allow me to use dialogs.  Another possibilty may be creating my own UI that demonstrates a few simple options like which printer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the returned component will allow the user to change all of those options, especially the JCOMPONENT_UI component.  I'm not sure what the PANEL_UI component looks like.  It is possible to build your own, using the javax.print package and its subpackages, but I think you'll find that it's a lot of work, and the ServiceUIFactory already does a good job of it.

Comment: Ok thanks, when I get back to that project ill mess around and try to make what your saying work :)